# Why NGINX rewrite rule does'nt working in online server but it is working in offline?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting

So here is the rewrite rule I made in website.conf

it is working in offline server. but when I put it inline it doesn't work it produced 404 not found. Our server is nginx/1.8.0

```
location / {

rewrite ^/chi-siamo/?([a-z-]+)?/?$ /chi-siamo.php?chi=$1 last;

rewrite ^/categoria/?([a-z-]+)?/?([a-z0-9-]+)?/?$ /categoria.php?cat=$1&id=$2 last;

rewrite ^/nazione/italia/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /nazione.php?nazione=italia&pg=$1 last;

rewrite ^/nazione/italia/?([a-z0-9-]+)?/?([a-z0-9-]+)?/?$ /nazione.php?nazione=italia&regione=$1&id=$2 last;

rewrite ^/nazione/?([a-z-]+)?/?([0-9-]+)?/?$ /nazione.php?nazione=$1&id=$2 last;

rewrite ^/ricerca/?([a-z0-9-]+)?/?([0-9]+)?/?$ /ricerca.php?search=$1&pg=$2 last;

}
```

Comment: Is it the same version you're using locally?

Comment: nope I am using nginx/1.10.1 in offline

Comment: Sir Magnus what you think is the problem?